# How to disable Firebase cache (Persistence) in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

After restarting the application, Firebase is loading locally cached data. How can I remove this locally cached data & retrieve fresh data only?

I've read that Firebase provides 10Mb by default cache. I think if we can find a way to disable this default cache, the problem might be solved.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

Following is the restart code

```
    finish();
    //System.exit(0);
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GAME.class));
```

Following is the Listener

```
 final DatabaseReference LC = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("XYZ");
 LC.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {


            if( dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("XX")) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                XX= value;
                Toast.makeText(GAME.this,"XX:"+XX, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(XX.equals("Match"))
                    tableManager(0); //new Table
                else
                    tableManager(1); //old Table
            }
        }
.....
```

Comment: I faced the same problem, but the problem wasn't the cached data, was the sync was not specific enough. Try to improve the "keepSynced(false);" and let's see if that works

Comment: I tried LC.keepSynced(false); it is also not working. :(

Comment: Every sync must be done before any database operation is executed, the best way to do it so is doing it the application class, is this helpful in any way?

Comment: I can't understand can you please post the sample code statements for it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is:

1. The node to be sync must be specific
2. The syncing must be done before any database transaction, a good way to do this is in the Application class

For creating an Application class, create a class that `extends` the `application` class, then in the Manifest register it as your custom application class using the `name` tag.

```
public class CustomApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        //Here keep everything sync with the keepSynced(true) method
    }
}
```

And in the manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".some.package.CustomApp">
```

Comment: How will I access AppCompatActivity? activity_main.xml ?

Comment: You don't have to, this happens when the Application is created, which is before any Activity is created

Comment: Ok Inserted this code in my application. Now should I call CustomApp somewhere or just run the code?

Comment: In the manifest, by using the "name" tag you define wich application class is used, if there is none, then the default class will be use

Comment: Yeah, i did but it is now working with both FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); & FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);

Comment: @DaniyalTariq don't get it? What does that have to do with any of this?